# Flutter dio image upload not working throws server 500 error, but works in postman

Tags: flutter, dart, image-upload, dio

This is my postman request with a header `auth` token.

[image: **this is my postman type with headers <code>auth</code> with token**]

I am trying to upload image everything is set up as mentioned with dio docs and exactly the same as postman parameter but 500 error is thrown, could not find any mistake here. been stuck here like for 3 hours.

please find any mistake here i am stuck here thanks! (ps: postaman file takes only image file i.e jpg, png other file excluding images will also throw same as 500 error like app is throwing)

and my dio request is:

```dart
Future requestChangePhoto(
      String wardenToken, String wardenId, File imageFile) async {
    String fileName = imageFile.path.split('/').last;

    print(fileName);
    print(getWardenPhotoChange);

    FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
      "wardenId": "${wardenId.trim()}",
      "photo": await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile.path,
          filename: fileName, contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg")),
    });

    Dio dio = new Dio();

    dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    dio.options.headers["authorization"] = "$wardenToken";

    await dio
        .post("$getWardenPhotoChange", data: data)
        .then((response) => print(response.data));
  }
```

This is my `ImagePicker` and request:

```dart
 var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: imageType == ImageType.camera? ImageSource.camera: ImageSource.gallery,

    imageQuality: 50, maxHeight: 500, maxWidth: 500

    );
        print(imageFile);

        NetworkHandler networkHandler = NetworkHandler();
        networkHandler.requestChangePhoto(xybaData.WardenToken, xybaData.wardernId, imageFile);
```

This is my error:

[image]

Comment: I also faced the same issue so i decided to get the filename with this line String fileName = imageFile.path.split('/').last;  and then added it to the fromFile() method and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the latest updates, `content-type` is not treated by `Dio` as a "normal" header. What I mean is that it ignores that header.

To make it work, set the `dio.options.contentType` property instead.

Wrapping it up, instead of this:

```
 dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

try this:

```
 dio.options.contentType = 'application/json';
```

**Bonus**:

When creating a `Dio` instance, you can pass a `BaseOptions` to its constructor like this:

```
Dio dio = Dio(
    BaseOptions(
        headers: {"authorization": wardenToken},
        contentType = "application/json",
    )
);
```

I believe its a cleaner way of doing things :D

Comment: Thanks. It Helped, Dont know why this answer is not accepted yet.